# My weather indicator is stuck on menu bar

Tags: my-weather-indicator

I'm using Ubuntu 14.4 I'm facing that problem with my weather indicator applet in menu bar it's always stuck while logging in or sometimes while using my Ubuntu I tried a lot of things to solve it like reinstall the indicator and removed the package and the application itself by sudo remove and remove purge, so is anyone know how to solve this problem or how to relaunch it to work properly as it should to be?